# How can we know the release date of apt repository

Tags: ros, apt, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to know exact timing of releasing apt repositories for both "ros" and "ros-shadow-fixed".
Is there any trigger or hook by which we can know exact time when new list of apt packages are released?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245806/how-can-we-know-the-release-date-of-apt-repository/) by [Yuki Furuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/4030/yuki-furuta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik there is no hookable infrastructure, but the syncs are announced on the [ROS Discourse site](http://discourse.ros.org) in the [release category](http://discourse.ros.org/c/release).

Note that these announcements cover the main ROS package repositories only. Mirrors might need additional time to catch up with their sources.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuki Furuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/4030/yuki-furuta/) on 2016-10-17**:
I see. Thank you for information!